# How to filter multiple elements from the list if matching specific pattern?

Tags: android, string, list, kotlin

I have list of `Work` model elements.

Work has paremeters like:

```
id,
title,
number,
version number
```

I would like to have only Work elements where `version number` is not null and take the highest `version number` of existing elements.
For example my list has Work elements like (in order title, number, version)

```
Running (120:1)
Running (120:2)
Running (120:3)
Climbing (55:1)
Climbing (55:2)
Climbing (55:3)
Climbing (55:4)
```

My result in the list after filters should be

```
Running (120:3)
Climbing (55:4)
```

My code so far:

```
    private fun List<Work>.filterByVersion(): List<Work> {

                work.version_number != null
        }.filter { work -> ("${work.title} ${work.number}:${work.version_number}").contains("no idea of regex here")
     }
    }
```

I was thinking something like inner search with `{work.title} ${work.number}:` then find in here the max value of `{work.version_number}`.

Answer (score 1):

The following code works for me:

```
private fun List<Work>.filterByVersion(): List<Work> =
    groupBy { it.number }.map {
        it.value
            .filter { work -> work.version_number != null }
            .maxByOrNull { work -> work.version_number!! }
    }.filterNotNull()
```

First we convert current list into a `Map<Int, List<Work>>`, where the key is `Work.number` then we map resulting `Map` into a `List<Work>` by filtering non null values of `version_number` and finding the max value of it.

---

Another variation:

```
private fun List<Work>.filterByVersion(): List<Work> =
    groupBy { it.number }.values.mapNotNull { works ->
        works
            .filter { work -> work.version_number != null }
            .maxByOrNull { work -> work.version_number!! }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data class Work(
  val id: Int,
  val title: String,
  val number: Int,
  val versionNumber: Int
)

val works = listOf(
  Work(1, "Running", 120, 1),
  Work(2, "Running", 120, 2),
  Work(3, "Running", 120, 3),
  Work(4, "Climbing", 55, 1),
  Work(5, "Climbing", 55, 2),
  Work(6, "Climbing", 55, 3),
  Work(7, "Climbing", 55, 4)
)

fun List<Work>.filterByVersion() = this
  .groupBy { it.number }
  .map { (_, list) -> list.maxBy { it.versionNumber } }

val result = works.filterByVersion()

result.forEach(::println)
```

Comment: Why do you use here _ as a parameter could you explain it please?
= this (it is just my list, which next I make on thsi groupBy etc.)

Comment: @chrisChris The underscore stands for a variable which is not used later in the code. This is not a must, it could for example be _(number, list) ->_. But when somebody reads the code that person would assume that _number_ is used later.